# Fobidden in apache server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, digital-ocean

**Solved it!** Turns out that i was missing the permissions on the /var folder too... Thanks to everyone!

---

I have a website running in `/var/www/html`.

The owner of this folder is the user www-data and the group www-data as well.
Apache is running under the user www-data and the group www-data.

The permissions are set in 775 for all directories, files and subdirectories under `/var/www` included.

The configuration of directories in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is the following:

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

SELinux is not active.

My `.htaccess` file looks like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article/(.+)/(.+)\.html index.php?page=article&id=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html index.php?page=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tripeala.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tripeala.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Despiting this configuration I'm getting a Forbidden message when trying to enter the website.

On the apache error log I'm getting an error that says `'access to /index.php denied (filesystem path '/var/www') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path'`

Comment: Marcos, are you able to access a static file (like  test.html) in the root by also disabling .htaccess? If SeLinux is disabled and folder permissions are as you said then it should be an apache conf or rewrite issue somehow. Actually even your naked domain rule is not working - you should add <Directory /var/www/html> for AllowOverride All for that. Interesting, I wish I could take a look at the server, really curious.

Comment: The error is explicitly stating that the permissions on at least one of the directories forming your document root are not 0775 (they shouldn't be 0775 anyway, but /var, /var/www and so forth should be readable and executable by www-data)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved it!** Turns out that i was missing the permissions on the /var folder too... Thanks to everyone!